# Не удается включить Hyper-V в Windows 10

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

Я собираюсь начать учиться работать с Docker'ом, однако он выдает мне сообщение о том, что контейнеры Hyper-V не выходит включить.

[image]

Именно это выдает, когда пытаюсь включить hyper-v через меню компонент. Этот код ошибки связан с обновлениями Windows, но в моей системе нет возможных обновлений.
Удаление virtualbox, центр устранения неполадок - все это не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Характеристики windows. systeminfo говорит, что hyper-v полностью поддерживается. Пожалуйста,помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте консоль PowerShell от имени администратора.

Выполните следующую команду.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

Comment: Все так же. Не найдена сборка, на которую имеется ссылка.                                 + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand

Comment: У Вас точно нет ни каких запретов на обновления системы? Посмотрите файл hosts там ни какие ресурсы не завёрнуты локально?

Comment: гляньте этот пост https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746926/13023647

Comment: Попробовал все варианты оттуда, безуспешно. Что за файл hosts?поиск молчит

Comment: @SergeyRolinskiy, если Вам про этот файл мало что известно, то лучше почитать о нём. Лежит тут: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Comment: @SergeyRolinskiy, Вы не дали ни какого ответа про обновления ОС.
Что у Вас выводится если запустить команду: `net start WuAuServ`.

`cmd` запускать от имени Админа

Comment: В начальном посте написал, что обновлений ОС нету, центр обновлений подключен разумеется. Файл hosts пустой.

Comment: @SergeyRolinskiy Вам следует обновить систему. Что показала команда?

Comment: сделайте `net stop WuAuServ`
зайдите в `C:\Windows` переименуйте папку `SoftwareDistribution`
затем `net start WuAuServ` и попробуйте установить компонент.